# updating ubuntu while dual booting with windows 8

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, upgrade

i have a machine that has windows8 preinstalled,i dual booted ubuntu 13.04 with it and everything is working fine, im a bit new to linux so had a few doubts..

1. when 13.10 /14.04 LTS is released, how do i upgrade 13.04 so as to keep the dual boot intact? will i have to perform a bootrepair again ?
2. will updating ubuntu every 6 months slow down the performance of the machine? is there a specific way to upgrade without losing performance ?
3. if i want to upgrade ubuntu to 14.04/13.10 with a clean install and still keep windows 8 dual boot ,how do i do it ? is it merely wiping the ubuntu partition and doing a clean install and boot repair? or anything else ?

thanks for all the help guys ..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if you wish to update, do so normally, it wont affect your dual boot
2. updates are mainly to perfect what is on system, updating is usually to improve performance + features already installed and people try to do that without loss of performance
3. if done through update manager its done for you affecting ONLY ubuntu installation itself

Comment: Just to add, ubuntu updating doesn't even see/care about the windows installation, and only changes its own stuff.

Comment: thanks a lot ! :) i hope everything works out well ..i hate the UEFi thing .. :/